# Xcode unity3d bitcode enabled error

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

Xcode getting bitcode enabled error, i tried to disable it but doesn't work.

```
ld: '/Users/mypc/Documents/my document/Unity-
iPhone/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/libUMUnityAnalytics.a(UMUnityGameAnalytics.o)' 
does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled 
(Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the 
vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
```

please help me as stuck here from last 2 days now.

Comment: Do you mean you tried to disable bitcode for the target via Build Settings > Build Options > Enable Bitcode? If so do you get the same error message?

Comment: libUMUnityAnalytics.a required bitcode enable, when i disable bitcode its giving more errors

Comment: its linking error